# skipping ]]> in a CDATA section of xml version 1.1

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, cdata

I am using a CDATA section but the text consists of some characters and hence it is getting closed and i am getting parsing exception.

```
<xyz><![CDATA[\..\..\\..\..\\..\..\\..\..\\..\..\\\boot.ini]]>&#0;</xyz>
```

i found the below code from some site:

```
// Add a CDATA section to the root element
Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
CDATASection cdata = doc.createCDATASection("data");
element.appendChild(cdata);

// If "]]>" appears in the text, two CDATA sections will be written out
cdata = doc.createCDATASection("more]]>data");
element.appendChild(cdata);
```

The problem in using the above logic is i do not know which element i am reading from DB will contain "]]>" so that i can write two CDATA sections.

Need ur help on this.

Comment: Hm. The error im the example seems to be the 0-char after the section, not the section itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping arbitrary text with CDATA sections is error prone because they cannot nest.

Use [entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to escape the text instead.

However, if you really want to use CDATA sections, [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Uses_of_CDATA_sections) of the Wikipedia page might help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common mistake to imagine that you can put arbitrary text in a CDATA section simply by adding `<![CDATA[` at the start and `]]>` at the end. You need to check first whether the data contains `]]>`. If it does, the usual remedy is to split it after the first ']', so if the content is `A]]>B`, it gets written as `<![CDATA[A]]]><![CDATA[]>B]]>`.

A good way to avoid this problem is to avoid serializing the XML "by hand", and instead using a serialization library to do the job.